# How do you map the output of a Spring stored procedure execute?

Tags: spring, stored-procedures

I am using Spring and stored procedures to retrieve data from a mySQL database.  I have the stored procedure and parameters working OK but I'm having problems mapping the result set.  At the moment I have some truly ugly code to get the values and I'm sure there has to be a better, cleaner and more elegant way. Can anyone guide me to a better solution?

After the stored procedure class, I have:

```
List<String> outList = new ArrayList<String>();

Map<String,Object> outMap = execute(parameters_map);

List list = (List) outMap.get("#result-set-1");

for (Object object : list) {
    Map map2 = (Map) object;
    list.add(map2.get("runname"));  
}

return outList;
```

runname is the column from the database query.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post your SQL query?

Comment: Can't show you exact but it boils down to: Select name From table where type = ?.  name is a Varchar(45) field, stored procedure gives a list of names.

Answer (score 1):

Example from [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html) using RowMapper:

```
public class JdbcActorDao implements ActorDao {

private SimpleJdbcCall procReadAllActors;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
    this.procReadAllActors = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withProcedureName("read_all_actors")
            .returningResultSet("actors",
            BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Actor.class));
}

public List getActorsList() {
    Map m = procReadAllActors.execute(new HashMap<String, Object>(0));
    return (List) m.get("actors");
}

// ... additional methods
```

}

Comment: Yes, I tried that, got nulls.  I used .returningResultSet("names",
            BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(String.class));

Comment: Your resultset contains only single String column? In that case you should try to use [SingleColumnRowMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/SingleColumnRowMapper.html) instead, because, as i known, BeanPropertyRowMapper is for POJO classes.

Answer (score 0):

took a while to interpret the Spring docs but I finally got there.
My solution:

```
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                                                      .withProcedureName("DistinctRunNames")
                     .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
    simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("environment", Types.VARCHAR));
    simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("username", Types.VARCHAR));
    simpleJdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("test_suite", Types.VARCHAR));
   SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("environment", environment)
                                                    .addValue("username", username).addValue("test_suite", testSuite);
    Map map = simpleJdbcCall.returningResultSet("runnames", new ParameterizedRowMapper<RunNameBean>() {
           public RunNameBean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                  RunNameBean runNameBean = new RunNameBean();
       runNameBean.setName(rs.getString("runname"));
       return runNameBean;
       }
          }).execute(parameters);
    return (List) map.get("runnames");
```

Had problems with expected parameters versus actual, had to break up the simpleJdbcCall object.  Maps the results into a list beautifully.
Thank you for answers, helped me to learn about Spring mapping.